# Open FileStream with path of memoryStream as FilePath

Tags: c#

I have a question,a complicated one!!!

I have some external class library that needs path of file.
my application load the file to  the memory stream.

I want to give it some path (to the external dll) that will redirect it to the memory stream in order to get the file, instead of to the file system.
(the dll working with FileStream).

for example:
If I have file (in fileSystem) with name : C:\MyFile.txt
I want to load the file to the memoryStream and provide the external dll somepath, something like "MyMemoryStreamPath" and it will load the file from the memory and not from the file system (it will "Think" that it's file system path, but actually its a path of memmoryStream).
just to remind you, the dll working with FileStream.
I know that it's a complicated question any idea will be accepted. :)

Comment: I don't believe this is possible unless you mount a virtual filesystem.

Comment: You could just stream the file contents back out to the disk into a temporary location and point the external library at that location, but the question is, why load it into a stream in the first place?

Comment: Actually, you might be able to get away with deriving a custom class from `FileStream` and overriding its behaviour to access your `MemoryStream` instead of a file.

Comment: but the class that will get the path belongs to the external dll. I Can't override it's behaviour!

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I misread that part. What is your goal? Are you aiming for performance (to avoid reading the same file again) or security (to prevent changes to the original file)? If it's the latter, you should just go with @Charleh's suggestion and copy the file to a temporary location.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do that. If you have permission issues, you can save your stream to an [IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7dzh4ws.aspx). It has plenty of options and you can get path of the saved file through relfection.